# How to optimize use of n_jobs within nested sklearn objects?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

I am running an ensemble model using StackingClassifier with xgboost and several other classifiers and would like to take advantage of the most number of cores available at all times (96 in my case).

If I have to choose, it seems that the best places to parallelize would be within the classifiers themselves and not in the StackingClassifier since it only has to run cross validation and not tree building, however even when setting n_jobs=1 in StackingClassifier, Random Forest uses all cores, but then xgboost is not using more than one core. How can I configure this so that xgboost uses all available cores?

```
rfc = RandomForestClassifier(
                            n_estimators=1000,
                            max_depth=None,
                            max_features = 0.2,
                            bootstrap=True,
                            random_state=0,
                            verbose=2,
                            n_jobs=-1
                            )

xgb = XGBClassifier(
                    n_estimators=1000,
                    max_depth=24,
                    max_features=0.2,
                    bootstrap=True,
                    objective="multi:softprob",
                    num_class=2,
                    colsample_bytree=0.3,
                    gamma=1, 
                    learning_rate=0.01,
                    subsample=0.9,
                    random_state=0,
                    verbosity=2,
                    nthread=-1,
                    n_jobs=-1)
estimators = [
    ('rfc', rfc)
    ]


stacker = StackingClassifier(
                    estimators=estimators, 
                    final_estimator=xgb,
                    stack_method="predict_proba",
                    verbose=2,
                    cv=2,
                    n_jobs=1,
                    passthrough=True)

calibrator = CalibratedClassifierCV(
                                    base_estimator = stacker,
                                    method="sigmoid",
                                    cv=2)
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this issue: cpu usage remains close to 100% during xgboost's fit. I'm using windows 10 with latest sklearn & xgboost